# How to send datagram packet through Internet?

Tags: java, networking, datagram

I'm trying to make a basic datagram client/server program with Java.

I've made the server cling to port 9321 on my local computer.

I've made the client on port 9320 on my local computer,
then send the data over wireless router network (192.168.1.100) at port 9321
the program works!

then i try to send the packet over (via router)internet IP 139.195.12.183(my ip) at port 9321
but it didnt work!
there is this exception:

```
java.net.SocketException: Interrupted function call: Datagram send failed
```

i've set the router to forward any request for port 9321 to my computer
and then i've set exception for the firewall on my computer on that port

this is the source

```
String SERVER = "139.195.12.183";

sendString(SERVER, 9321, "Greetings"); <<


private void sendString(String IP, int port, String toSend) {
    byte[] buf = toSend.getBytes();
    DatagramPacket packet = null;
    try {

        packet = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length, InetAddress.getByName(SERVER), port);

        ds.send(packet);<<
    }catch(UnknownHostException e) {
        System.out.println("unknownhostception");
    }catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println("ioception "+e.getMessage());

    }

}
```

i've had another answers from another forum it said:

> "The way routers work, you can't see your external (WAN) internet address from your
>   internal network (LAN). If that's what you are trying to do, there's nothing wrong, it 
>   just won't work.
>
> Ian."

any explanation?

Comment: Just to clarify - global network == internet? Your local PC does have a publicly available IP address (the IP you mentioned belongs to a carrier)?

Comment: ah yes i mean internet.
the private network is my router.

Comment: If you use IP datagram, always think about its TTL.

Comment: Can't see anything wrong with the code. I'd grab wireshark to have a look at what's being sent.

Comment: @brice i've install wireshark, the packet is not even being sent (there is no packet)

Comment: @KeenanGebze OK, That means it has nothing to do yith your network. Could you post the code that sets up your Datagram Socket so I can reproduce the problem myself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some steps that you can take:

1. Check that the code works across two machines on your LAN.
2. Check that `ping <target-ip>` works on your machine.
3. If it does, check your local **and** LAN firewall settings for blocking on the port/protocol.
4. If the ports are unblocked change the port to something else. Some ISPs will block certain ports.

Some more reasons why this error could come up:

- <s>UDP (I Assume?) datagram too large.</s>
- <s>Client side error that doesn't affect reception (Have seen similar things with some network stacks where the error was spurious.)</s>

Post a link to your code from patsebin or something if you want more info.

Comment: the first step is success
ping target is success (without hops!)
router settings(forwarding) to my computer is enabled (on port 9321)
i think the port 9321 isnt blocked by the ISP (but i'll try it!)

Comment: What is the TTL value set for the IP datagram? TTL of 1 will only last on the first router and never go beyond it. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_to_live

Comment: good catch eee, I forgot to mention that. Although I'm not sure Keenan would get sending exceptions.

Comment: DatagramSocket cannot set the TTL, so i have to use the MulticastSocket? what is the difference between them?

Comment: @KeenanGebze yeah, a real nuisance with DatagramSocket  (IP unicast datagram) MulticastSocket (IP multicast "datagram"), right? check this bug issue http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=4740586

Comment: @KeenanGebze As an alternative, use timeout setting for DatagramSocket to avoid longer blocking on the receive side.  `DatagramSocket.receive will block forever until a packet is received, unless you have previously set a timeout ...set a data buffer large enough to hold the data you expect to receive ...will hold the data received. If the data is larger than the buffer size, excess bytes are silently discarded` http://www.techrepublic.com/article/using-datagrams-in-java/5099670